# Ionic capacitor library for voice-to-text transcription

Tags: android, library, ios, angular, typescript

I am part of a non-profit NGO, we are developing an app to fight against violence and one of the features of our app is the possibility to ask for help by saying a specific word or phrase
We are using ionic with capacitor

The requirements would be:

1. Continue running with the phone blocked, if not indefinitely, at least for 10 minutes
2. Prevent self-disconnection when you say a word, for example, the google app when it detects a word and then silence, decides it's over
3. Works on ios and android

That we have tried:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/speech-recognition

Thank you very much